# store external web service in web.xml

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jsp

if I want to store a external web service url in the web.xml file, how I must proceed?, in this way?:

```
<service-ref>
<service-ref-name>PublicApiService</service-ref-name>
 <service-interface>
</service-interface>
<wsdl-file>
    http://nxxxx/example/Services/PublicApiService.wsdl
</wsdl-file>
```

What I should put on the service-interface if the web service is external?. I use eclipse

Thanks so much

Comment: check this link: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxwsclientdd.html

Comment: Thanks but it isn't clear for me because I have this mistake:              cannot Deploy cloud2000
Deployment Error for module: cloud2000: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Deployment error for service-ref PublicApiService.
Service references with generated service interface must include WSDL and mapping information.. Please see server.log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the client stubs of the service.
You can use [ws-import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) for generating the client stubs:

```
wsimport -p your.package.name -s gen -d bin http://nxxxx/example/Services/PublicApiService.wsdl
```

This will generate the needed Java source files. Execute it in your project root dir.

After that you have to change your web.xml file:

```
<service-ref>
    <service-ref-name>PublicApiService</service-ref-name>
    <service-interface>
        your.package.name.PublicApiService
    </service-interface>
    <wsdl-file>
        http://nxxxx/example/Services/PublicApiService.wsdl
    </wsdl-file>
</service-ref>
```